# F# Define Function input type/ Prevent type missmatches

Tags: function, f#, type-mismatch

I should probably start out by saying im new to F# and that this is without doubt a rookie question.

I have been doing F# for like two months now and a thing that I in general find frustrating about F# is the contant errors saying. "Here was expected to have type something but was given type something else."

I remember my teacher saying that unlike other languages then F# cant figure out on its own what types you are referring to.

So my question to you guys is how do you define the type that an input for function has?

example:

```
let FoneTwo y x =
  System.Math.Sqrt(x^2+y^2)

printfn "%A" (FoneTwo 2.2 3.3)
```

This errors that a float is expected but has type String. Where on earth does this string come from? In the function call im clearly using floats. So i guess i need to specify somehow that y and x is a float but how?

In general Im not only after an answer to this example but a general rule or method to keep track of this issue? Because in general this happens alot.

can someone enlighten me?

Comment: `(^)` is a string concatenation operator for ML compatibility. You want to use `(**)` instead e.g. `x ** 2. + y ** 2.`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the operator `^` is not power, it's string concatenation (for ML compatibility).

You should use the `pown` function instead:

```
System.Math.Sqrt(pown x 2 + pown y 2)
```

And you can shorten it to:

```
sqrt(pown x 2 + pown y 2)
```

There is an operator `**` available but that's for floats, so you would have to change your code to:

```
sqrt (x ** 2.0 + y ** 2.0)
```

But I would use `pown` instead.

Comment: So should take as that if i get a type missmatch then it is probably one of the operators that isn't doing what i think it is doing?

Comment: Yes, by using an operator that works with a specific type, in this case string, type inference use this information to derive the type of the function.